# Can I replace a broken glass porch light with some sort of translucent plastic?

Tags: repair, light-fixture

While replacing the bulb of my porch light, the glass portion fell and broke. Below is a picture of the other one that is still intact.

I’d prefer not to replace the whole light if possible as I have two front lights that match, I rent my place, and I live in a duplex so want to match across both sides of the building.

Is it reasonable to commission a custom glass replacement (no idea where to go or if that is possible?)

Alternatively, could I use some sheet of semi flexible translucent plexi or plastic to fashion a durable replacement? Would the light be too hot? It currently houses a standard 60 watt equivalent LED bulb.

[image: light fixture with three sided glass enclosure]

Comment: Check for any labels inside the light

Comment: Larger towns and cities here in the US have stores which specialized is lighting: lamps, globes, fixtures, etc. Many will have extensive stock and catalogs with replacement glass. This may be a common enough design that you can buy or order a replacement.

Comment: a plastic milk jug might be the right size

Comment: notched trowel render - I didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: Sorry for you coming all he way to the DIY site, just to be told, you must inform the landlord and pay for two new fixtures that have to be installed by a professional.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend fixture replacement. If the fixtures are on standard junction boxes then it is not so hard to do. I've replaced the above my front door twice (first time replaced incandescent with fluorescent bulb and second time with integrated LED). The catch is that because this is a rental, you are not allowed to do this yourself, which means arranging with the landlord to have an electrician replace it. Of course, since you broke it, the landlord may make you pay for it. However:

- Glass will likely cost a lot. A new fixture might cost anywhere from $ 20 to $ 100 or more per fixture (plus installation). But any custom glass is likely to cost quite a bit too, and it will still be an old fixture.
- Plastic is simply not a practical option. The reason: **heat**. You are using a low-power LED, and with that there is likely not any real problem with plastic. But if the next tenant insists on using a 60W incandescent bulb (Why? I don't know. People are crazy. But if the fixture is rated for it, they can do it.) And that 60W bulb may generate enough heat that the plastic will melt, and get worse from there. Yes, there are plastics designed to handle heat, but that would be a custom job like the glass (and not cheap). Cut up a milk jug? Fine for short-term use. Not for a permanent fixture repair.

You *may* be able to convince the landlord that this really wasn't your fault. Glass can get more brittle over time, particularly with use outside (hot & cold) and lighting (rapid temperature changes, at least in the 60W days). Of course, that doesn't apply if it broke because you dropped it 6 feet onto the ground :-)

Comment: yeah, it's going rusty time to replace!

Comment: Agreed it is very old! I’m sure it’s the original fixture from when the house was built in the 70s. I’m ok with paying for it since it is ultimately my fault - it would not have broken if I wasn’t replacing the bulb (wanted to put in LED for obvious reasons) - but I’m a generally very careful and handy person so I do partially blame how old and crappy it is for why it came loose :)

Comment: Not a heat problem with led, and if the next tenant changes back, it's their problem, OP will be long gone! A note inside would suffice.

Comment: @Tim That all *should* be OK. But [Murphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) says the fire marshal won't be happy at the end of the investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're renting replacement of the lumiere is going  to involve a registered electrician to do this legally. so your best option is to replace the glass.

Take the intact glass to a plastics fabrication shop they can cut and bend sheet plastic for for you at not much cost or you could try doing it yourself heating it over a pop-up toaster or radiant bar heater until flexible.

In operation heat should not be a problem a 9W (actual power) LED is not going make enough heat to damage the plastic.

Comment: I think this is what I will try first. Im looking for even just a temporary cosmetic fix that will look ok while I wait for my landlord to arrange replacement.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how carefully you fashion a replacement, you will not be able to create an exact match to the unbroken lamp. I recommend that you make *two* replacements (and retire the unbroken glass) so your lamps will remain a matched pair.

Now that you are relieved of the pressure to make your new light look like the old one, you are free to change the design to make it easier to construct -- score a sheet of Lexan and fold it, use three glass panels and metal corner pieces, or whatever can be made to fit.

If it discolors or rattles or anything, you can try something different. You can change it because the lights only have to match each other.

---

@jsotola suggests a plastic milk jug might provide suitable material and might even be the right size.